# Combine the columns with null values in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have SQL query which fetches results like this

```
Column1 Column2     Column3 Column4    Column5 Column6 Coulmn7
A-66001 46063       137039  0-82-A0-A0 NULL   NULL     NULL
A-66001 46063       139045  NULL       NULL   NULL     NULL
A-66001 46063       141051  NULL       40     NULL     30
A-66001 46063       237164  NULL    NULL      20       NULL
```

I want a result combining all the rows like this .

```
Column1 Column2     Column3 Column4    Column5 Column6 Coulmn7
A-66001 46063       137039  0-82-A0-A0 40        20     30
```

I tried using Max function but that did not work for string . Need the solution at the earliest

Comment: What do you mean `max()` did not work for "string"?  What happened?  `max()` works fine on strings.

Answer (score 2):

Use `max()`:

```
select column1, column2, min(column3) as column3,
       max(column4) as column4, 
       max(column5) as column5, 
       max(column6) as column6, 
       max(column7) as column7 
from table t
group by column1, column2;
```

I am guessing that you want to really group by the first two columns and any arbitrary value for `Column3` is appropriate.

Comment: i want group by coulmn1 and column2 , coulmn 3 is not required but i want all the  null from column4,column5,column6,column7 and display only one column displaying the values in that column

Comment: I tried using max(column4) this earlier ,but it  did not work for me , but now this is working

Comment: `min()` and `max()` work on almost all types, including strings (sometimes they are not allowed on big data types such as blobs, but otherwise they are allowed on almost all types).

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
select
(select column1 from table where column1 is not null limit 1) as column1
(select column2 from table where column2 is not null limit 1) as column2
(select column3 from table where column3 is not null limit 1) as column3
(select column4 from table where column4 is not null limit 1) as column4
(select max(cast(column5 as int)) from table where column5 is not null limit 1) as column5
(select max(cast(column6 as int)) from table where column6 is not null limit 1) as column6
(select max(cast(column7 as int)) from table where column7 is not null limit 1) as column7

from table
```